# Use different log4j config files for same application running different process

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have developed a simple spring based application which has three different class containing `main` method.

```
class P1 -> runs process P1
class P2 -> runs process P2
class P3 -> runs process P3
```

Currently these processes use single log configuration file i.e. `log4.xml`, which is loaded from classpath by default.

I want to do it like this

```
class P1 -> runs process P1 -> Uses log4j_p1.xml
class P2 -> runs process P2 -> Uses log4j_p2.xml
class P3 -> runs process P3 -> Uses log4j_p3.xml
```

How can I achieve this in Spring ?

Note: It is plain Spring application. I am a newbie to Spring. If there is a Spring specific way using `Dependency Injection` , please do let me know.
If there is not, how can we achieve it in plain `JAVA + log4j` way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this may be to use log4j's `log4j.configuration` system property. You can pass this system property to each process and reference the relevant `log4j.xml` file in question.

For example, assuming that `log4j_p1.xml` is on the classpath, then when you run `P1` add the following system property to the command that starts the Java process:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_p1.xml
```

And then the same for `P2` and `P3`.